# How to check if a file is in a certain directory then to pop error if it is not there if it is not there then add it

Tags: python, arcgis, gpx

We download GPX files from email, and I'd like to run a script where it selects the GPX and says whether it's there or just adds the GPX into another file.

I have a script where it adds the GPX into a file but then I need it to check if it was already in the file and to warn us and this part in the script doesn't work.

```
    import glob
    import os.path
    import shutil

    SRC_DIR = 'C:/Work'
    TARG_DIR = 'C:/Work/GPS_N32'

    GLOB_PARMS = "*.gpx"

    for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(SRC_DIR, GLOB_PARMS)):
        if file not in glob.glob(os.path.join(TARG_DIR, GLOB_PARMS)):
            shutil.copy(file,TARG_DIR)
        else:
            print("{} exists in {}".format(
                file,os.path.join(os.path.split(TARG_DIR)[-2:])))
```

The error message should read this gpx is already there! And if the gpx is not there then a message should say added files.

Comment: This code won't run anyway because `dir_src + filename` wouldn't give any real file path because you would be missing `\` at the end of `dir_src`. Have you tried running it?

Comment: Yes I have ran it but I get an error that then pops up another file shutil.py?   It then has in red this --> with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:

Comment: that's exactly the error coming from what I said. read up on how to format file paths, and how to check file existense - specifically read up on `os.path` and `pathlib` to see which is right for you

Comment: Okay so I also have this other code I edited in above now it copies the file but never gives the error. is the problem the else: statement?

Comment: `glob` is a generator, checking if something is `in` it will exhaust it. try and replace all your `glob.glob(...)` with `list(glob.glob(...))` to avoid that

Comment: Same thing as before. Would it have to check first then add?

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import os.path
import shutil

SRC_DIR = r"C:\Work"
TARG_DIR = r"G:\GPS\_in\Trimble\GPS_NEW"
GLOB_PARMS = "*.gpx"

os.chdir(SRC_DIR)

for gpxfile in glob.glob(GLOB_PARMS):

if os.path.exists(os.path.join(TARG_DIR, gpxfile)):

    print("{} already exists in {}".format(gpxfile, TARG_DIR))
else:
    shutil.copy(gpxfile, TARG_DIR)
```